# Load Pymacs & Ropemacs only when opening a Python file?

Tags: python, emacs, ropemacs, pymacs

I use **Pymacs** to load **ropemacs** and **rope** with the following lines in my **.emacs** file as described [here](http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/).

```el
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
```

It however slows down the start-up of Emacs significantly as it takes a while to load **Ropemacs**.

I tried the following line instead but that loads **Ropemacs** every time a Python file is opened:

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")))
```

Is there a way to perform the `pymacs-load` operation when opening a Python file but only if **ropemacs** and **rope** aren't loaded yet?

Answer (score 9):

In my **.emacs** I have:

```el
(autoload 'python-mode "my-python-setup" "" t)
```

And in a separate file **my-python-setup.el** I keep:

```el
(require 'python)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
;; Initialize Pymacs
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
;; Initialize Rope
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)
```

This way, **Pymacs** and **ropemacs** will be loaded only once. This happens when the first **.py** file is opened.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `eval-after-load` is for.

```el
(eval-after-load "python-mode"
  '(progn
     ;; Do whatever you need to do here. It will only get executed
     ;; after python-mode.el has loaded.
     (require 'pymacs)
     (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")))
```

You'll need to write "python" instead of "python-mode" if you use **python.el** instead of **python-mode.el**.

I actually have my **ropemacs** loading code in a separate function that can be called interactively. This is because occasionally **ropemacs** crashes for me, and when it does I just call that function to reload it.

Comment: And as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2736153/1497596) indicates, `eval-after-load` runs only *once*, so it is ideal for initially configuring a mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```el
(defun my-python-hook-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'pymacs)
  (autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
  (autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
  (autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
  (autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
  (autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
  (ac-ropemacs-setup)
  (setq ropemacs-confirm-saving 'nil)
  (ropemacs-mode t)
  (define-key python-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)
 )
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-hook-mode)
```

where `ac-ropemacs-setup` is defined in the **auto-complete** module:

```el
(defun ac-ropemacs-require ()
  (with-no-warnings
    (unless ac-ropemacs-loaded
      (pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
      (if (boundp 'ropemacs-enable-autoimport)
          (setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t))
      (setq ac-ropemacs-loaded t))))

(defun ac-ropemacs-setup ()
  (ac-ropemacs-require)
  ;(setq ac-sources (append (list 'ac-source-ropemacs) ac-sources))
  (setq ac-omni-completion-sources '(("\\." ac-source-ropemacs))))
```

This solution assume that you use **auto-complete** at the same time.

Comment: As [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2736153/1497596) indicates, using a mode hook isn't really the right approach here because a mode hook runs for every new buffer to which the mode applies. But making use of **auto-complete** is a good idea.