# Emacs c-mode autoloading failed

Tags: emacs, emacs23, c-mode

I want to load my file named "my-c-setup.el" when the c-mode is loading. So, I'm using the function "autoload".

With my python setup, it works well :

**lang.el**

```
(autoload 'python-mode "my-python-setup" "" t)
```

**my-python-setup.el**

```
(require 'python)
; ...
```

---

I'm trying to do the same with the c-mode, but i does not work :

**lang.el**

```
(autoload 'c-mode "my-c-setup" "" t)
```

**my-c-setup.el**

```
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
; ...
```

When I try to open a file in c-mode (test.c for example), I have the following error :

```
File mode specification error: (error "Autoloading failed to define function c-mode")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autoload is not what you're looking for. What it does is simply load some code the first time it is needed, which is a handy way to extend Emacs' functionality while still keeping the start-up time low.

To solve your problem, we gotta think about what you really want to do: do you simply want some of your code to be loaded at some point, or do you want buffer-local customizations for ever buffer that is in `c-mode`?

If you simply want Emacs to load your code at start-up, either put your code directly into your `.emacs` file or use `load-file` or `require` instead of `autoload`:

`load-file` simply takes a file name, loads the lisp code in that file and evaluates it. So if your code is in a file named "/path/to/my-c-setup.el", you could put the following line in your .emacs, and the code will be loaded on every start-up:

```
(load-file "/path/to/my-c-setup.el")
```

Perhaps you don't want to give the absolute path name for every file you load. In that case, you could use the function `load-library` instead which is similar to `load-file` but tries to find the given filename in any of the directories stored in the variable `load-path`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to")
(load-library "my-c-setup.el")
```

The advantage is that you have to do the `add-to-list` part only once, and all subsequent calls to `load-library` will be able to find code in that directory.

An alternative way is the provide/require mechanism: you can make your .el-file "provide" some feature by putting a `(provide 'feature)` call in it, e.g.

```
(provide 'my-c-mode-customizations)
```

Then put an according `(require 'feature)` in your .emacs file, and your code will be loaded as well:

```
(require 'my-c-mode-customizations)
```

However, if you want your code only be loaded when `c-mode` is activated on a buffer, the way to achieve that is through Emacs' [Hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html#Hooks) mechanism:

> A hook is a variable where you can
>   store a function or functions to be
>   called on a particular occasion by an
>   existing program.

Most major modes provide a customizable hook variable to which you can add functions that will be called whenever the major mode is invoked. For instance, c-mode provides `c-mode-hook`. In order for your own customizations to be called whenever c-mode is turned on for a buffer, put them in a function, say, `my-c-mode-customizations` and add the following line to your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-customizations)
```

Of course, you still need `autoload` for Emacs to actually find the definition of that function.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp's [autoload](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Autoload.html) does not call a function when a file is loaded but tells lisp that the function is available and that the given file provides it. Whenever someone calls the (not yet defined) function, the file is loaded.

I think that `c-mode` is already defined and thus fails to re-register.

Answer (score 1):

Autoload doesn't do what you think it does.
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Autoload.html

What you probably want are mode-hooks or eval-after-load.
See [eval-after-load vs. mode hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736087/eval-after-load-vs-mode-hook) for the difference between the two.