# How can I use eval-after-load for c/c++ mode settings in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I hope to add additional paths to `ffap-c-path` in c-mode/c++-mode, and I prefer the lazy load mechanism. There are two choices for me:

- use `add-hook` for `c-mode-hook`/`c++-mode-hook`
- `eval-after-load`

But as @sanityinc said in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736087/eval-after-load-vs-mode-hook), it seems here the latter is better. So I add the code like below:

```
(eval-after-load 'cc-mode
'(progn
  (require 'ffap)
  (setq fap-c-path (append ffap-c-path '("/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include")))
  )
)
```

However when I later opened a c source file and find that `fap-c-path` still the old value. According to the docs, I can use `eval-after-load 'cc-mode` or `eval-after-load "cc-mode"` if `cc-mode` is a library/feature; but neither works here. I take a look at the source code where cc-mode is defined, and find that it uses a `cc-provide` instead, is it the root cause?

BTW: I also tried the `add-hook` approach; the new path DOES append, but every time I open another c/c++ file, the code is executed once and finally `ffap-c-path` contains many duplicated paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mis-spelled `ffap-c-path` as `fap-c-path`.

You would also be better using `add-to-list`, which actually deals with duplicate entries, only adding a new list item if it wasn't already present.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `add-to-list` instead:

```
(eval-after-load 'cc-mode
  '(progn
     (require 'ffap)
     (add-to-list 'ffap-c-path "/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include")))
```

That way, you guarantee that duplicate values are not inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will remember it. But this time it is due to my typo.