# Add a TeX symbol in the Emacs init file

Tags: emacs, emacs23, auctex

I am trying to add the following code to my `.emacs` init file:

```
(TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref))
```

But I cannot get it to work. I get the following error when running `emacs t.tex` (`t.tex` is here a sample text file) from the command line:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `.emacs':
Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-add-symbols
```

I am using GNU Emacs version 23.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. My `.emacs` init file looks like

```
(setq TeX-auto-parse t)
(setq TeX-electric-escape t)
(setq reftex-label-alist '((nil ?e nil "~\\eqref{%s}" nil nil)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref))
```

If I enter `ESC-:` (i.e. running the command `eval-expression`) and enter
`(TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref))` at the prompt it works fine. (That is after running this, I can enter `\eqref` in the buffer and it works as expected.. But this is not a good solution, having to enter this code manually each time I edit a file.. That is the reason why I try to set it up in the `.emacs` file..)

**Background information for this question:**

I have a problem with using the AucTeX style `amsmath.el`.. it seems that it is not loaded properly on my machine.. For more information, see [Using \eqref with RefTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118640/using-eqref-with-reftex).

Comment: `(eval-after-load "latex" '(TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref)))`

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that it does not work ..

Comment: The error you reported (`Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-add-symbols`) should be fixed, right?  To make `eqref` work you have to delete the file in `/var/lib`, as I suggested on TeX.SE.

Comment: yes :) But when I enter `C-h v TeX-symbol-list` `eqref` is not defined...

Comment: I hoped I could fix this it without deleting the file :)

Comment: Why doesn't `eval-after-load "latex"` work here?

Comment: The following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736087/eval-after-load-vs-mode-hook indicates that mode hooks are run later than `eval-after-load` code.. Is it possible to use a mode hook here?

Comment: Try `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref))))` or `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref (ignore)))))`

Comment: Thanks again.. But it does not work. It seem that it the mode hook is run just *before* (not *after* as I was hoping for) emacs loads the file `/var/lib/auctex/emacs23/amsmath.elc`..

Comment: Yes, `LaTeX-mode-hook` is run as soon as LaTeX mode is activated, `/var/lib/.../amsmath.elc` is loaded when the file is parsed and AUCTeX sees that your LaTeX source contains a `\usepackage{amsmath}`. But `TeX-symbol-list` should contain a `("eqref" 1)` and a `("eqref" TeX-arg-ref (ignore))` and AUCTeX should prefer the one with the longest definition, the latter in this case.  This is AUCTeX works, see the [AUCTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Adding-Macros).

Comment: @giordano Yes! Very nice, I missed your point.. After adding the `ignore` argument in `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref (ignore)))))` it seems to work :-) But my `TeX-symbol-list` looks strange now. It contains one `"eqref"`, one instance of `("eqref 1)`, two instances of `("eqref" TeX-arg-ref)`, and one instance of `("eqref" TeX-arg-ref (ignore))`.. :-)

Comment: @giordano You may also add the solution now as an answer here (and also at tex.stackexchange.com, if you want) and I will accept them.. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to evaluate the code after `LaTeX-mode` is activated, otherwise you get the error `Symbol's function definition is void: TeX-add-symbols`.  You can add that function to the hook of `LaTeX-mode`.  In order to override possible other `eqref` macro definitions, you should add a dummy `(ignore)` to the definition of the macro.  This code, in your `.emacs`, does the trick:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (TeX-add-symbols '("eqref" TeX-arg-ref (ignore)))))
```