# Add command or environment to AucTeX autocomplete list

Tags: emacs, lisp, auctex

I use a lot the autocomplete feature for commands and environments of AucTeX, via the `TeX-insert-macro` and `LaTeX-environment` functions. But is there a way to add to the built-in list more commands and macros (`\enquote{}`, `\noindent`, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to add support for macros and environment is writing a style file, it's documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files The relevant functions are [`TeX-add-symbols`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dadd_002dsymbols) and [`LaTeX-add-environments`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002dadd_002denvironments).

To add new macros and environments without creating style files see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17249399/2442087  For example, to add the `foo` macro and the `bar` environment add this to your init file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (TeX-add-symbols "foo")
        (LaTeX-add-environments "bar")))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only changes the face of the command; it doesn't add it to the list of autocomplete macros---as far as I could see.

Comment: Actually those commands don't change fontification but add macros and environments to `TeX-symbol-list` and `LaTeX-environment-list` variables, that is what you want. So explain what you've done.  Note you may need to restart Emacs to make changes effective.